# Building a single drop-down menu from 2 arrays

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to build a drop-down from 2 arrays, and I've got the options working but the nested foreach loop is not working, so each option in the drop down has the same title (first item of array $linkText). What is the correct way of doing this? Thanks.

```
$content.='<select onChange="window.location.href=this.value">';
      $content.='  <option selected="selected">Choose one</option>';

 foreach($dateLinks as $item1){ 
               $content.='<option value="'.$item1.'">';

               foreach($linkText as $item2){
                 $content.='   '.$item2.'  </option>';
}
}

$content.='</select> ';
```

The arrays look like this:

```
$dateLinks = array(
    '/latest/potm/previousmonths/Oct2003',
    '/latest/potm/previousmonths/Nov2003',
    '/latest/potm/previousmonths/Dec2003',
    '/latest/potm/previousmonths/Jan2004'
);

$linkText = array('Oct2003', 'Nov2003', 'Dec2003', 'Jan2004');
```

Comment: whats your array look like?

Comment: I've edited main post to show you the data

Answer (score 0):

Ok nevermind sorry. I managed to do it with a little more research, by combining the arrays:

```
 $c = array_combine($linkText, $dateLinks);

      foreach($c as $key => $value){ 
               $content.='<option value="'.$value.'"> '.$key.' </option> ';
               }

     $content.='</select> ';
```

Comment: i appreciate your research :)